# MapView tile coordinates

Tags: android, tiles, android-mapview

Is it possible to determine the coordinates of the tiles that are visible in a MapView, relative to the first tile in the upper left corner of the *entire* map (including the invisible part)? I can't seem to find a way to get the tile coordinates ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote a script that can be found here which suits my needs:
http://mapki.com/wiki/Lat/Lon_To_Tile